# Cakephp find('list') and Translate behavior

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP 3.

I have an accounts table. Each Account belongs to a Country. Countries table is internationalized using Translate Behavior, so it can store countries names for each language.

```
     class CountriesTable extends Table
     {
        public function initialize(array $config)
        {
        $this->table('countries');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->addBehavior('Translate', ['fields' => ['name']]);
        }
```

Note that "name" field is internationalized through the Translate behavior, so it's not present in the countries table.

Then in the AccountsController I want to get the list of the countries using the active language:

```
....
$countries = $this->Accounts->Countries->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
.....
```

The problem is that it's not getting the translations from the **i18n** table as expected. I already have coded the maintentance actions for the internationalized countries table, and everything is working OK, but this simple `find('list')` is not working.

One more detail: in the Mysql logs I see it has launched this query. Note that the countries table has only two fields: **id** and **code**, but the **displayField** is **name**.

```
SELECT Countries.id AS `Countries__id`, Countries.code AS `Countries__code` FROM countries Countries LIMIT 200
```

btw, it's getting really difficult to switch from 2.x to 3.x.

Comment: Check the class of object `debug($this->Accounts->Countries)` - _is_ it a CountriesTable object? The usual reason for code in model classes not having any effect - is them not being loaded at all (I refer to `the countries table has only two fields: id and code, but the displayField is name` and the sql not matching)

Comment: In Eclipse debugger expressions `$this->Accounts->Countries` it returns `Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo`. After executing the code, `$countries` variable is of type `Cake\ORM\Query`. Anyway, how can't it be loaded if it's well linked in the *AccountsTable* with `$this->belongsTo('Countries', [
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);`

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem after a lot of investigating. If my case, accounts table is not internationalized, but the related table countries it is.

The problem is that I didn't set the locale in the Accounts controller. After putting this line before the finds, everything worked fine:

```
I18n::locale('spa');
```

So I guess that if you don't stablish the locale using **I18n**, **Translate** behavior won't work at all. I should load it in **AppController** to make it application wide available.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: If at run time the locale is the default locale [the translate behavior won't do anything](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/ORM/Behavior/TranslateBehavior.php#L197-L199) - I guess that's the main point of confusion.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I'm not sure that this is the right behavior,.. I mean, it should always take the translations even if I haven't changed the language from the default one. Also, in [CakePHP-2.x locale was taken from the `Config.language` as a fallback for the own model locale](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/TranslateBehavior.php#L535-L536), so it was always set. I've solved it setting the language in all cases in AppController beforeFind.

Comment: `I'm not sure that this is the right behavior` - It is the designed behavior. The translate behavior assumes the [default language](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/config/bootstrap.php#L100) content is in the original table, if you don't change the locale, or change it to the default - there will be no attempt to retrieve translated values.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, specially regarding efficiency. I've been working with CakePHP 1.x and 2.x series for years, and always dropped the translated fields from the original table, so I always need to go to the translations table. Can't remember now where did I read it or why did I use to do it...

Comment: @AD7six I've been trying to implement this behavior, but now I see why the current locale and the default locale never differ, unless you call `I18n::locale()`. It's because I'm using `DispatcherFactory::add('LocaleSelector');` in my bootstrap. It takes the locale from the HTTP request and [sets the *default locale*](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Routing/Filter/LocaleSelectorFilter.php#L67). If you don't change it using I18n::locale(), the Translate behavior will never do anything.

Comment: It's probably worth ticketing that.

Comment: @AD7six I've opened [this ticket](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7208) in CakePHP github. Thanks and regards.